# Formula for difference between two numbers on a wall clock in clokwise direction

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It's my first post in math.stackexchange.com.
I got a necessity to find out the clockwise difference between two numbers on a wall clock. For example, difference between 12 and 1 is 1 where as the difference between 1 and 12 is 11. Actually what I need is number of clock wise steps required reach number b from number a on a clock. 
While writing an application, I struck writing this function.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use arithmetic [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) 12.

Comment: can someone tell me why down vote for my question please....

Comment: Probably you got caught in the debate on [PSQ](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9330/should-problem-statement-questions-be-an-issue-for-the-election)s... or simply because this is a [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240803/how-i-subtract-times) question.

Answer (score 1):

i am writing a C function

Code

```
 int clockstep(int a, int b){
    int steps =0;
    if (a<=b)
    {
       steps = b-a;  
     }
     else
    {
       steps = 12-b+a;
     }
  return steps
 }
```

means you take input from user than compare it if 1st $<=$ 2nd then simply (2nd-1st) is your answer otherwise do (12-2nd+1st).

Comment: i have written logic and answer below the code

Comment: I think your else clause should be $12+b-a$ since the two answers should agree mod $12$.

Comment: else is (12-b+a) what is wrong.

Comment: $12-b+a\not\equiv b-a\pmod{12}$ Try some numbers and see if you get what you want. For example, $12$ and $1$, then $1$ and $12$.

Comment: Thanks everybody and thanks @iostream007.Is it not 12-a+b? I think it is! I'm new to this site, can anybody tell me why negative vote for my question?

Comment: @pinkpanther: yes, it should be $12-a+b$.